# Hide trigger (img) for popup, when I click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, elementor

I have image in header, and when I click on the image a popup opens. I need to hide this image when popup is open and show when popup is closed.[image]
Second Image: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQo4D.jpg)

Website:https://clavis-schule.de/home-dev/

Comment: Please add your code to the question, and don't post code images.

Comment: Please Add Valid Code Here so that we can have look and provide some solution to you.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, I edit post. Website created with Elementor, its hard to add code, so I add link on page. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making use of event listeners you can swap out classes/styling of the element that is firing the event. Onclick works too but I personally only use it on button elements, choose what you prefer most

In case you're using jQuery you can use

```js
$('img').on('click', (e) => {
    e.toggle()
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/toggle

alternatively if you're not using jQuery you could use

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("d-none")
}

// (more specifically)
document.getElementById("menu-img").classList.toggle("d-none")
```

where `d-none` is a bootstrap class. It could simply be a custom class as well

```css
.d-none {
    display: none
}
```

You will need to toggle the image back when clicking away the modal and since you've provided no code example I can only tell you to figure that part out on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
Website developing with Elementor, so its hard to paste code. Link to page:https://clavis-schule.de/home-dev/.

I have added an id="hideoncl" for the image. And before </body> added this code

`<style>
.d-none {
    display: none;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("hideoncl").classList.toggle("d-none")
</script>`

Comment: With this code the section is always hidden

Comment: I see, I don't know elementor enough to give you an exact answer but you should be able to add custom code anywhere I'm pretty sure. You should only apply the class once you've clicked on the image so make sure you wrap the selector inside a function. Try adding this function to your image using onclick. If need be you might be able to add the onclick using javascript again but you'll have to trial and error with that yourself as I don't have an environment with elementor set up

Comment: Thank you so much for help! I made it!
`<style>
.d-none {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("hide-header").setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction()"); 
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("hide-header").classList.toggle("d-none")
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('show-menu').setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction2()"); 
function myFunction2() {
   var element = document.getElementById('hide-header');
  element.classList.remove('d-none');
}

</script>
`